# trouble getting Hello World / gas / Mac OS X to work

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to write Hello World in GNU assembler for Mac OS X, but it's bus erroring before it can print "Hello World".

[hello.s](https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/gas/hello/freebsd/hello.s):

```
.global start

.data

.equ stdout, 1

.equ sys_write, 4
.equ sys_exit, 1

.equ kernel, 0x80

msg: .asciz "Hello World!\n"
.equ len, .-msg

.text

start:
    push $len
    push $msg
    push $stdout
    mov $sys_write, %eax
    sub $4, %esp
    int $kernel
    add $4 + $4 * $3, %esp

    push $0
    mov $sys_exit, %eax
    sub $4, %esp
    int $kernel
```

Trace:

```
$ clang -c -o hello.o hello.s
$ ld -o hello -macosx_version_min 10.6 hello.o
$ ./hello
Bus error: 10

$ gdb hello
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/andrew/Desktop/src/mcandre/gas/hello/freebsd/hello 

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x0000000000002000
0x0000000000002000 in msg ()
```

I'm basing my code off of a couple things:

- [Working NASM / Mac OS X code for Hello World](https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/nasm/hello/freebsd/hello.asm)
- [Working Gas / Linux code for Hello World](https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/gas/hello/linux/hello.s)

I took the semantics from NASM / Mac OS X and the syntax from Gas / Linux.

I also tried the example program on the GNU Assembler Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler#Example_Programs), but it also bus error's.

I filed a bug report with Apple due to its GNU assembler being horribly out of date (as 1.38). They said to use clang instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Specs:

- ld64-134.9
- clang 4.1
- Xcode 4.5
- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- MacBook Pro 2009

Answer (score 2):

In answer to what you did wrong, I'm not sure. It's been a while since I've used assembly but clang didn't like the .equ statmentes on my mac. When I replaced those, it ran fine. (To be honest I prefer NASM, although I use the one from macports.)

I created a simple .s file that will compile with clang, I had one issue with the string length.. 
(perhaps it's a bug?) where I store the length in $len, but when I use $len it doesn't work.. but using a hard coded number does.

I compiled the code with:

```
clang -c -o hello.o hello.s -arch i386
ld -o hello -macosx_version_min 10.6 -arch i386 hello.o
./hello
```

hello.s:

```
/* defines */
.set sys_exit, 1
.set sys_write, 4
.set stdout, 1
.set kernel, 0x80

// TEXT SECTION
.text

/* write function */
.macro write str, strSize
    // length of string
    push \strSize
    // the string
    push \str
    // to file descriptor
    push $stdout
    // what we want to call
    movl $sys_write, %eax
    // call the kernal
    call _syscall
    // free the stack
    addl $12, %esp
.endm

/* define main function */
.globl start

/* impl. main function */
start:

    // write(string, long)
    // if I use $len i get a bunch of letters
    write $msg, $14 //$len

    // exit(0)
    // if i print out $len it is 14
    push $0 //$len
    movl $sys_exit, %eax
    call _syscall

/* call kernal 
 * 
 * so you don't have to do sub $4, %esp
 */
_syscall:
    int $kernel
    ret

// DATA SECTION
.data
    /* our string */
    msg: .string "Hello World!\n"
    // using len: .long $14 causes the same issue as . - msg
    // where the string does not end at 14
    // perhaps someone else knows why..
    len: .long . - msg
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: well I've tried to use `$-msg` and then `.-msg` but if you want have an environment for assembly on *nix, I can add to my answer for a working example that I believe is easier to do; via MacPorts and NASM.

Comment: @mcandre If you want to see how I set up my assembly environment or would like to see how to make a universal binary for the mac I have uploaded a zip file, all code is in public domain [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B49KRMcMpMV1MnhqMzZVOHBfeFE)